# Installing ubuntu for the first time dual os

Tags: 16.04, windows-7, sony

I am new to Linux and i wanted to install Ubuntu onto my old Sony Vaio.  It meets all the requirements.  But when installing from a USB a get an error that says 'unable to install grub in /dev/sda' this is a fatal error

I have seen few topics on this sort of same message, but all the options that are given there, are not available when I try to install it.

Please help im already getting really frustrated because i tried it 10 times using different ways, but no luck so far.

I have looked at the "Unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda” when installing GRUB" thread, but the solution that they offer did not help me fix my problem.

Being new to ubuntu, i figure out where i can change the installation directory, by choosing 'Something else' during install, making the partition by myself and setting the path to that partition, and then installing it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda" when installing GRUB](http://askubuntu.com/questions/459620/unable-to-install-grub-in-dev-sda-when-installing-grub)

Comment: same problem, but that solution does not help me i tried that solution, but i have no option anywhere to change from sda to sdb

Comment: pls be more precise about what vaio it is - i believe there are a million models of  vaios, second did you have a look at the newest answer in https://askubuntu.com/questions/159918/cant-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7-on-sony-vaio-s-15-2012?rq=1 instead of `emacs` use nano to edit the file

Comment: @RyneIgnelzy, there's more than one solution there, so try them all if the first doesn't work. For the first solution, see [another answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/343352/616451). Notice at the bottom of the second picture, it says `Device for boot loader installation`. That's where you'd change it.

Answer (score 0):

Back in the days when I used Ubuntu and Windows in dual boot my steps to achieve this where:

1. Create 2 main partitions one for each system: you can do this with Windows or Linux install CD/USB it doesn't matter.
2. Install Windows on first partition;
3. Create a back-up copy;
4. Install Linux on second partition. Set grub as default boot-loader when asked.

I do not know what you did to install this dual boot system of yours and I will gladly help you with more information but you need to provide more information about what you did and how because you are pretty vague. To give you an example a useful information will be what O.S. you tried to install first?