# How launch VAIO SOny T13 in UEFI mode?

Tags: vaio, sony

How to launch Vaio Sony **T13** (Ivy Bridge - July 2012) in UEFI mode to install 12.04.1?

I tried long press <kbd>F11</kbd>, but doesn't work.

[How to boot into Live USB/CD with UEFI on latest Vaio S series?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162853/how-to-boot-into-live-usb-cd-with-uefi-on-latest-vaio-s-series)

Comment: have you tried f2 key? and delete key?

Comment: f2 = entering into bios but no efi bios option (confirm by VAIO link by phone)
del key I didn't try yet (I try tomorrow ) thank

Answer (score 0):

If you have "ASSIST" key on your laptop you need to use that button to power your laptop instead of POWER button. Power off your laptop then click assist button for 1-2 seconds. Your laptop will power on and bring a list of UEFI options for you. Select boot from usb/optical drive to boot the Ubuntu media with UEFI support.