# Unable to access BIOS in my laptop after installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: system-installation, bios, sony

I have a Sony Vaio S Series that came with Windows 7 and U installed Ubuntu 14.04 by creating a bootable USB, setting the boot priority in the BIOS and booting from it.

During the installation, I chose to completely erase my HD and install Ubuntu. The system installed correctly and I have been using Ubuntu and loving it =].

Today, however, I tried to install Windows alongside Ubuntu. I tried to change the boot priority in the BIOS to boot from my Windows CD but I just realized that I'm no longer able to access the BIOS screen! When I press <kbd>F11</kbd> during the laptop power-up, the message "Operating system not found" is displayed. I also tried <kbd>F1</kbd>,<kbd>F12</kbd>, <kbd>DEL</kbd>, <kbd>Fn+F2</kbd>, etc. but nothing worked.

I've tried googling for a fix, but everything I found was beyond my comprehension (I'm still learning how to use Linux). If someone could explain to me in layman terms what is going on here and how could I solve this I'd appreciate it a lot. If technical terms or procedures cannot be avoided, I'd ask you to please add some links explaining the concepts used.

Comment: The bios access has nothing to do with your operating system, because the bios loads before the OS location has even been identified.  So this is entirely between you and your user manual (or on-screen prompts).  Sony should be able to help, if all else fails. (Note: on my Vaio, I have to press and hold the 'assist' button during boot.  Yours may be different).

Comment: Something in [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/150174/sony-vaio-with-insyde-h2o-efi-bios-will-not-boot-into-grub-efi) question (first answer) tells me that it is indeed not a problem "caused" by ubuntu but perhaps it can be fixed by tweaking something in it? Unfortunately I lack the required knowledge to fully grasp the answer in there...

Comment: You will have to consult your hardware manufacturer for how to get into the bios.

Comment: @psusi: I'll start looking into that. But based on my comment above, don't you think this can be fixed by tweaking some ubuntu files?

Comment: @h3now, no, as stabledog said, the bios has nothing to do with your os.

Comment: @psusi: And is it possible that when I decided to wipe the contents of my HD, something affected the BIOS?

Comment: only if there is a bug in your bios.

Comment: @Stabledoq: The assist button used to work for me as well, but since I wiped my HD, pressing the assist button has the same effect as pressing the power button.

Comment: I have the same problem with my Sony Vaio laptop not being able to access the BIOS. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @WilliamRoss Unfortunately, the only solution I could find was to remove the hard disk from the notebook, connect it into another computer (one which I could access the BIOS), install Windows and then put the HD back in the notebook.