# No permission to copy files (live CD)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, permissions, 14.10

I'm trying to dual boot Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu and a solution I have come accross requires me to do some copying and pasting to get grub to appear. (My problem is that grub never shows up).

**Here are the instructions from [the AskUbuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/a/157062/344930):**

---

mounting /dev/sda3 from live-session

```
copy EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi to EFI/Boot/
rename EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi to bootx64.efi.old
rename EFI/Boot/grubx64.efi to bootx64.efi
```

now it booted directly into grub2, but without win7 entry

after loading ubuntu I edited

```
/etc/grub.d/40_custom
```

adding

```
menuentry "Windows 7" {
    set root='(hd0,gpt3)'
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
```

and after

```
sudo update-grub
```

---

**My problem**:

When I try to copy those files using the Files app, I'm given a permission error. I have no idea how to proceed. Please please help me out. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is because you need to launch the file browser with admin privileges, and to do that, open a terminal window (ctrl-alt-t), type `sudo -i` to become root user, then type `nautilus` to launch the file browser.

summary:

```
ctrl-alt-t
sudo -i
nautilus
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does this work in Ubuntu 14.10?

Comment: It worked for me. Just that I saw similar questions on this site and none of them worked for 14.10. This one works though. It didn't solve my problem though but thanks!