# Unable to dual-boot Ubuntu 14.04 with pre-installed Windows 8.1 (Sony Vaio S series Laptop)

Tags: dual-boot, boot-repair, vaio

I recently installed Ubuntu on dual-boot mode with pre-installed Windows 8.1. When I turn on my laptop, it boots straight to Windows without showing boot option or GRUB. However, I can boot to Ubuntu by doing, in windows, an Advanced Restart --> Boot from device, and I can see Ubuntu here. By doing this I can get into GRUB and boot into Ubuntu without any problem. I have tried all the ways I could find on the Internet and failed. Asking a question is my last resort, so I really hope someone could help.

P.S. I tried doing boot repair and this is the URL to pastebin: http://paste.ubuntu.com/10744176/

Comment: You might just want to install GRUB to /dev/sda (the disk itself, no partition, so no number behind sda!). This procedure is described [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/88432/367990).

Comment: Does not rEFInd work, I thought that was one of the better solutions. Sony modifies UEFI to boot by description and only description that works is "Windows". That is not UEFI standard.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/150174/sony-vaio-with-insyde-h2o-efi-bios-will-not-boot-into-grub-efi But generally better to rename /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi and make that file be grub or shim.  http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Comment: The solution could be as simple as checking your boot order in your UEFI. Make sure that your HDD (might be labelled as ubuntu) is at the top of the list, with Windows Boot Manager below it.

Answer (score 0):

Grub menu will appear if you press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> during loading Grub.

For permanent change you'll need to edit your `/etc/default/grub` file -- place a "#" symbol at the start of line `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0`.

Save changes and run `sudo update-grub` to apply changes.

Documentation: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2