# Ubuntu won't boot after booting into Windows 10 once

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows, windows-10

First I installed Windows 10 on my system. Then I installed Ubuntu. After the installation is complete, I rebooted and grub came up and I booted into Ubuntu without an issue.

Next I re-booted and went into Windows. Then again tried to reboot and Grub won't show. I was taken directly to Windows. I even picked Ubuntu from the boot menu. Still go to Windows.

In windows, if I open the windows partition editor, it won't show the ubuntu partitions. In my other machines, they are shown as raw. Any idea whats happening? Tried boot repair and also disabled secure boot. Nothing is working :-(

Comment: Have you taken out USB at the time of reboot(after installation)?

Comment: @Ashu No I haven't

Comment: That means you might have either installed in USB itself or may be you were trying ubuntu rather than installing.

Comment: @Ashu Aaa nope... The usb is 8GB... The root partition I created is 28GB and home is 150G. And I can see the windows partitions.

Comment: Have you tried actually shutting down windows instead of rebooting?

Comment: @terdon Yes I did. I also tried to open the fi partition through a partition manager in Windows. The ubuntu efi file wasn't there. But it's showing up in the boot menu.

Comment: I think that Windows will hibernate instead of shutting down by default. Do you see the POST message after rebooting or does it go straight into Windows?

Comment: @terdon I see the post msg. I also went to the bios boot menu and selected Ubuntu. But still going to windows

Comment: Just got it fixed! Ran boot repair in advance mode.. Set it to re-install grub. Repair Windows boot files, Also un-ticked  secure boot. Now its working! Any idea what happened?

Comment: What brand/model system? Some need work arounds to boot Ubuntu as they do not conform to UEFI spec. Copy to /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2247186 and:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/150174/sony-vaio-with-insyde-h2o-efi-bios-will-not-boot-into-grub-efi
Sony, HP & others:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 and:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/597052/can-not-boot-anymore-after-a-boot-repair

Comment: Make sure you have turned​ of secure boot and fast startup

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to run a boot repair from a Windows media disk/USB. When you go into Advanced mode run the repair and reboot.

I've seen Windows for some reason overwrite/corrupt the boot loader. Some instances I have received only the grub menu, or grub screen without one of the options, like loading Ubuntu or Windows. Usually once you repair the boot file it will work going forward.

Comment: Then the OP should edit his post to reflect the solution or use the "Answer your question" and not hide the answer in comments. I just saw his answer because it's like the 6th one deep.

Comment: Odd in deed. Thanks for voting to close the question.

Comment: I think they to that extra btw