# After booting up windows 10 once, grub wont show up

Tags: dual-boot, 15.10, windows-10

I think i am having the same problem as in this question, [Ubuntu won't boot after booting into Windows 10 once](https://askubuntu.com/questions/739404/ubuntu-wont-boot-after-booting-into-windows-10-once)

although this never got answerred and i do not know if the information in the comments are enough to help me

How do i fix it? It just happend to me, and i hope i havent lost any data.

Answer (score 0):

Simply putting this into the windows cmd as admin fixed it, thats all!

```
  bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```