# Installing Ubuntu in Boot Mode UEFI and secure boot on.Any Problem?

Tags: dual-boot, secure-boot

I am using Windows 8.1 with *UEFI* Boot Mode and secure boot is on. I read somewhere that you should turn off *secure boot* to install Ubuntu properly. I had installed Ubuntu on my different laptop and it is working fine with Windows 10 along with Ubuntu on *UEFI* boot and *secure boot* OFF.Now i want to install Ubuntu on my laptop with windows 8.1 previously installed.So,the question is that,is there any problem to install Ubuntu on it with secure boot ON,or i have to change *secure boot* to OFF?

Comment: Depends on whether your laptop manufacturer does follow Microsoft's guidelines, or they decided to be sloppy. If they do follow MS's guidelines, you shouldn't have to.

Comment: How can i check that my laptop follows Microsoft's guidelines or not?I am using Sony Vaio.

Comment: Only way to find out? Try installing Ubuntu with Secure Boot on. :(

Comment: With Secure Boot on,  you can only boot from UEFI boot menu, not from grub. Also Sony has issues. It has violated UEFI standard that says NOT to use description as part of boot. And of course only valid description is "Windows Boot Manager". But there are work arounds, primarily if dual booting using the fallback or /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi which you create as a copy of shimx64.efi. http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/150174/sony-vaio-with-insyde-h2o-efi-bios-will-not-boot-into-grub-efi or use rEFInd.

Answer (score 0):

I would say turn Secure Boot OFF. It depends on the laptop, but I don't see a reason to leave Secure Boot ON.

I have a UEFI system, and I turned: Fast Boot, Fast Startup and Secure boot OFF.

Comment: Is there any problem if i install Ubuntu on secure boot ON?

Comment: @YKSingh There is a high probability that you will not have a successful installation with secure boot on. In addition, even if it is successful, there may be several issues with trying to run programs that require virtualization. As per OctaVive's (lack of an) answer, Secure Boot checks hardware-dependent code to see that it follows Microsoft's guidelines. Leaving it on is fine for Windows, but problematic for Linux.

Comment: Thanks @PatrickNegus,your answer will help me a lot. I Googling to convert secure boot ON to OFF,and i watched some steps with the help of Windows disk.Is that are correct method?The link is given where i read that stuff.

http://www.howtogeek.com/175641/how-to-boot-and-install-linux-on-a-uefi-pc-with-secure-boot/

It will be helpful for me if tell me that ,or if there is any other correct way to convert secure boot ON to OFF then please tell me.Help will be appreciated.