# efibootmgr issue

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I've got "Ubuntu 17.04" and "Windows 8.1" installed in Dual-Boot. But when I turn on the pc Windows starts by default, if I want Ubuntu I have to press "esc" then "f9" to enter the Boot Manger and then I select Ubuntu.
I want the GRUB or Ubuntu to be run first by default, how do I do that?

This is my boot order:

```
efibootmgr

BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,3000,0001,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0001* ubuntu
Boot0004* Network Adapter (IPv4 Legacy)
Boot0005* Notebook Hard Drive
Boot2001* USB Drive (UEFI)
Boot2002* Internal CD/DVD ROM Drive (UEFI)
Boot3000* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot3001* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot3003* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
```

I chaeged it to:

```
sudo efibootmgr -o 0001,0000,3000,2001,2002,2003

BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0000,3000,2001,2002
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0001* ubuntu
Boot0004* Network Adapter (IPv4 Legacy)
Boot0005* Notebook Hard Drive
Boot2001* USB Drive (UEFI)
Boot2002* Internal CD/DVD ROM Drive (UEFI)
Boot3000* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot3001* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot3003* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
```

So I shutdown the pc, turn it back up and windows starts by default anyway.

I reboot, enter Ubuntu and take a look:

```
efibootmgr

BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,3000,0001,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0001* ubuntu
Boot0004* Network Adapter (IPv4 Legacy)
Boot0005* Notebook Hard Drive
Boot2001* USB Drive (UEFI)
Boot2002* Internal CD/DVD ROM Drive (UEFI)
Boot3000* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot3001* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot3003* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
```

Nothing's changed...

Comment: change the boot order in your system settings

Comment: Can you be more specific? system settings Ubuntu,  WIndows, BIOS ...?

Comment: win8.1 is EFI there is no BIOS it is System Settings. not ubuntu settings or windows settings

Comment: Please look at my edited question

Comment: change the boot order in system settings (hardware settings)

Comment: What brand/model system? Some only like to boot Windows by description. But one work around is that hard drive entry works, so copying /EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi to /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi and then booting hard drive by default works. Boot-Repair should automatically do copy file with 'use standard EFI file':
http://askubuntu.com/questions/150174/sony-vaio-with-insyde-h2o-efi-bios-will-not-boot-into-grub-efi
Sony, HP & others:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Comment: @oldfriend All right so, thank you for your answer, this looks like It might be my case,  my pc is an HP Envy-17, but the procedure explained in the site looks pretty complicated and It scares me a little, I don't want to mess up anything.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I've found the solution to my problems:

## STEPS

1) Enter bios and disable legacy and secure boot mode.

2) Enter windows, open a terminal with admin privileges and disable the hibernation mode with:

```
powercfg -h off
```

3) (Always in windows) Disable the "fast startup/boot" option: go to control panel > power options > Choose what the power buttons do > change settings not currently available > uncheck the "Turn on fast startup (recommended)"

4)Ok now, shutdown completely, not reboot. Start the computer again and enter Ubuntu.

5)Search in your computer for "Boot Repair" run it and click "advance options" here check the "Backup and repair Windows EFI files (solves the [hard-coded-EFI] error" leave the others as they are, and click apply.

6) Once It's done shutdown and you are good to go.

When you start again you'll see the grub appear first thing.

And now typing

```
efibootmgr
```

I see the order I wanted at the beginning:

```
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,3001,0000,0002,0003,2001,2002,2003
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
Boot0001* ubuntu
Boot0002* Network Adapter (IPv4 UEFI)
Boot0003* Network Adapter (IPv6 UEFI)
Boot2001* USB Drive (UEFI)
Boot2002* Internal CD/DVD ROM Drive (UEFI)
Boot3000* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot3001* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
Boot3003* Internal Hard Disk or Solid State Disk
```