# Cant boot to Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: boot, boot-repair

Need some help here...I for some reason cannot boot into Ubuntu after multiple reinstalls.  Just cant figure out what is wrong.  The boot-repair output is http://paste.ubuntu.com/25733736/

I keep getting "No operating system found".  It's on its own disk, and nothing else plugged in.

Comment: sounds like a bios issue try switching between legacy and UEFI in your bios

Comment: Tried that....no combination worked

Comment: You have UEFI, do not try to boot with BIOS/CSM. What brand/model system? Some need various work arounds. Acer requires trust, HP, Sony need work arounds. http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 & http://askubuntu.com/questions/150174/sony-vaio-with-insyde-h2o-efi-bios-will-not-boot-into-grub-efi

Comment: I have a Lenovo H520S desktop.  Ubuntu is the only OS loaded on my SSD.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this will help anyone, but there might be an issue with UEFI, Lenovo, and non-Windows OS.

What I ended up doing was repartition the drive as MSDOS, creating new partitions, and installing Ubuntu in BIOS Compatibility mode.