# GRUB not booting as default manager

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

Details-http://paste.ubuntu.com/%3D9G4PK68b4C/
So  I have been trying to set grub as my default boot manager but windows keeps booting up directly even after running the boot-repair service and following the instructions given after the repair. ie. change default boot entry to boot on sda2/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi. Followed by setting boot orders. Can anyone point out where I am going wrong??

Comment: you have a HP. HP violates UEFI standard that says NOT to use description. And only valid description is "Windows Boot Manager". So you cannot set ubuntu entry as default. Various work arounds. Sony, HP & others workarounds:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789 Boot-Repair should automatically do copy file with 'use standard EFI file':
http://askubuntu.com/questions/150174/sony-vaio-with-insyde-h2o-efi-bios-will-not-boot-into-grub-efi
Some live with manually booting from UEFI boot menu. Some use rEFInd. many seem to use fallback.

Comment: huh.. well so that's the problem! Well i also tried the rEFInd boot manager and I can only remember it booted only the first time I changed the bootloader path. But since then it's nowhere to be found :(. So can rEFInd be used ?

Comment: With HP I think rEFInd needs to use the fallback entry or /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. Or copy rEFInd's .efi boot file to bootx64.efi.  Do not have rEFInd so do not know details.http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help oldfred! I'm trying to get this running.