# Install ubuntu alongside with pre-installed win10

Tags: dual-boot

I am trying to install Ubuntu alongside a pre-installed windows 10. After installation, I can only boot to windows.
I have tried running boot-repair, and however the computer still directly boots to windows.
This is the output of boot-repair and boot info summary:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/h2c5fy5wmx/

There is no grub menu and I am not able to find Ubuntu boot option in BIOS to change the priority order either.

I already disabled secure boot and using UEFI.

Comment: didyou disabled secure boot? have you tried the boot order keys? are you using bios or uefi?

Comment: Yes. I disabled secure boot. Using UEFI. What is boot order keys?

Comment: What brand/model system? I see mention of Sony. Can you directly boot ubuntu entry in UEFI boot menu? Most Sonys have needed work arounds. Boot-Repair should automatically do copy file with 'use standard EFI file':
http://askubuntu.com/questions/150174/sony-vaio-with-insyde-h2o-efi-bios-will-not-boot-into-grub-efi
Sony, HP & others workarounds:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789

Answer (score 0):

I fix this problem by copy the /EFI/ubuntu/shim64.efi to repalce /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi and /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi.

And enabled secure boot.