# Problems installing ubuntu getting into grub bash-like

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation

I tried installing Ubuntu from USB-drive, I installed succesfully restarted the computer as asked but then I got into this GRUB bash-like terminal. I tried using this method: https://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/ but that didn't work. I really need to install this and I have no idea how to repair, I have no other operating system on the computer.

Comment: What brand/model system? Post link from Boot-Repair's Summary Report.

Comment: this is the report: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/w8tj29KJ6n/

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? You still show a Windows boot entry and multiple ubuntu entries. Also some systems only boot from fallback or hard drive entry. I would first remove all old/duplicate entries to avoid confusion & then a total reinstall grub with Boot-Repair's advanced options.  use `sudo efibootmgr -v` to see details. https://askubuntu.com/questions/63610/how-do-i-remove-ubuntu-in-the-bios-boot-menu-uefi  You may need to boot using a work around or hard drive entry: http://askubuntu.com/questions/150174/sony-vaio-with-insyde-h2o-efi-bios-will-not-boot-into-grub-efi