# HP Notebook - OS boot manager (UEFI) failed load OS

Tags: bios

Pls help

HP Notebook (core i5,BIOS ver F.21)
OS Ubuntu 18.04 (64bit)

After successful installation unable boot normally. Showing 'No bootable device'.

By selecting 'Boot from EFI file'--> grubx64.efi file, booting normally.

How to resolve it.
-Jay

[image]
[image]

Comment: In UEFI settings can you make that entry first in Boot order? Some with HP said with newest UEFI, they could only change boot order in UEFI. Those with older UEFI could not change at all.  Efibootmgr (which grub also uses) can change it, but it only works once.

Comment: No i couldn't..

Comment: The other work around for HP has been to use the fallback or Hard drive entry. That is /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi which is the same path & file used to boot external drives. Older instructions have you copy grub boot files, but grub now installs that file. So does booting hard drive entry boot Ubuntu also? Boot-Repair should automatically do copy file with 'use standard EFI file':
http://askubuntu.com/questions/150174/sony-vaio-with-insyde-h2o-efi-bios-will-not-boot-into-grub-efi

Comment: It has been solved. Used 'rufus' for creative live usb (GPT - UEFI).

Answer (score 0):

It has been solved. Used 'rufus' for creative live usb (GPT - UEFI).