# How can I remove Windows 10 and replace with Ubuntu without losing data?

Tags: windows, microsoft

I have a Hp computer and would like to replace the Windows 10 completely with Ubuntu, without losing my data. How do I do this?

Comment: Step 1: Backup your data onto some other media. Step 2: Install Ubuntu. If you value your data, back it up. Re-partitioning, formatting, and installing a whole new Operating System are all *risky*.

Comment: Newer UEFI system or older BIOS/MBR configuration? Many convert to Ubuntu and find one application or one game they have to have that only works in Windows. So have full backup or way to reinstall Windows. Often better to start with dual boot if not used to Ubuntu. What model HP? You may need to update UEFI/BIOS & if SSD update SSD firmware. If UEFI:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI HP Notebook (core i5,BIOS ver F.21) OS Ubuntu 18.04 (64bit)
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206820/hp-notebook-os-boot-manager-uefi-failed-load-os