# Automatic booting problem in xubuntu 18.04

Tags: grub2

After doing software update,when i tried to reboot laptop ,I find that it is not self rebooting .So, I turned off laptop and restarted it but it showed me grub(2.02 version) and by default it was trying to boot in ubuntu but booting was not happening(only a blanck screen). So I revised the process and this time in grub menu 'through advanced option i select a linux generic version ' and booting happend succesfully.
"But my main problem is i have to do it manually everytime"

etc/default/grub folder detail:
G

```
RUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash reboot=bios"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Comment: Are you booting in UEFI mode from system, but install is BIOS, so you are using UEFI one time reboot into a BIOS install? If UEFI system, better to have UEFI installs. Query to check if UEFI or BIOS
`[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && echo "EFI boot on HDD" || echo "Legacy boot on HDD" `  Shows installer with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: output of the following command:Legacy boot on HDD

Comment: I find that this can be the reason"Remark: if the result is "Legacy boot on HDD", then either the BIOS is not UEFI type, or the BIOS is not set up to boot the HDD in UEFI mode. " . Now what should i do ?

Comment: What brand/model system. Microsoft has required vendors to install Windows in UEFI/gpt mode since Windows 8 released in 2012. So any hardware newer than 2012 is UEFI. Make sure you have UEFI set to boot in BIOS/Legacy/CSM boot mode, not UEFI. But should consider installing in UEFI mode, if newer system. But have to have good backups which you should have anyway.

Comment: My laptop is :HP 15-da0296tu  .                                                                                                 How to set UFEI set to boot in Bios/Legacy/CSM boot mode  ?

Comment: With HP many have said UEFI update helps. But they only can change UEFI boot order from within UEFI if they want Ubuntu to be default boot. Or they just select each time. It is either UEFI boot or CSM boot (which you do not want). CSM - UEFI Compatibility Support Module (CSM), which emulates a BIOS mode, only available with secure boot off. HP with optane
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1257230/dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-cannot-change-from-raid-to-ahci-through-bios?noredirect=1#comment2125560_1257230
& https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206820/hp-notebook-os-boot-manager-uefi-failed-load-os

Comment: should i disable csm boot option from bios ?

Comment: or should i convert ubuntu to ufei by creating efi  system partition ?

Comment: With UEFI, you really should have gpt partitioning. BIOS usually uses MBR(msdos) partitioning, but if only Linux, you can use gpt with BIOS boot. Systems are now UEFI, often better to use UEFI, but a few have so many issues with HP, the use BIOS or install rEFInd UEFI boot loader. HP Notebook (core i5,BIOS ver F.21) OS Ubuntu 18.04
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1206820/hp-notebook-os-boot-manager-uefi-failed-load-os HP Pavilion Gaming Laptop 15 -cx0049nr Disable Optane memory
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1134503/cant-boot-ubuntu-because-windows-10-rewrites-entire-efi-partition-solved

Comment: I think my laptop does not have any optane memory installed .