# Why is EFI boot-loader fallback failing?

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi

I am experimenting with EFI bootloaders and there's something I don't understand.
That's the situation:

1. I compiled by scratch grub2.
2. Formatted a USB drive with an EFI partition and placed the obtained 
   bootx64.efi and grub.cfg in /EFI/BOOT. The USB drives boots correctly.
3. If I replicate point 2 using an SSD drive, the system does not boot!
4. I found out that placing bootx64.efi in Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi makes the system bootable.

So, my question(s):

Is it possible that USB drives have a fallback different from hard drives?
Or, why is not my system booting from SSD using the fallback /EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi?

Thanks,

Alain.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sony VAIO with Insyde H2O EFI bios will not boot into GRUB EFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150174/sony-vaio-with-insyde-h2o-efi-bios-will-not-boot-into-grub-efi)

Comment: @AkshatZala I checked that thread but it does not answer why the default fallback EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi only works on the USB drive.

Comment: Do you have another OS on the SSD that *depends* on the fallback `bootx64.efi`? If so, you won't be able to use the fallback location to boot Ubuntu (without making your other OS unbootable). Also, `grub.cfg` should be at `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` (not necessarily on the EFI partition).

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]