issues Ubuntu 24.04 on my laptop
After attempting to install Ubuntu 24.04 on my laptop, I encountered issues with booting the system. Now, even after installation, I cannot access my computer. The screen stays black and not even USB devices work. My 4TB SSD is divided into two partitions, one with Windows (which disappeared) and another with Ubuntu 22.04 (which no longer responds). Upon booting, the screen hangs with the message 'Loading initial ramdisk...' and the Grub displays both the new Ubuntu and the old one, even after requesting overwrite. Any suggestions to resolve this booting issue and regain access to the system?
Notebook specifications:
RTX 3080 Ti GPU
64GB RAM
Intel Core i7 12th generation processor

Can you boot recovery mode from either install? Do you have fast boot setting off in UEFI? If you installed something to yoru USB installer, you may need to create new installer. If you can boot anything, run this: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed. Use often updated ppa version with your USB installer or any working install over somewhat older ISO.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair &
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/


Any action, the system freezes and the black screen appears.
I'm using a Chinese notebook called Style Note with a strange BIOS where nothing interesting appears.
Yes, I made another installer and it didn't work.
I can't access anything. Another point is that I only have access to the 'primitive' Grub, without even access to the basic boot-repair commands from Linux.


It seems you did not install nVidia driver as part of install. That is most common reason for black screen. You choose to install optional restricted drivers as part of install. You should be able to boot recovery mode to terminal and install driver from there. Are you pressing escape key as soon as UEFI vendor screen ends at startup. You may need to fully power off for "cold" boot not warm reboot.

I understand what you're saying, but as I mentioned, I only have access to the most basic Grub, the boot recovery doesn't work, and moreover, the BIOS I'm using is very limited, I'm using Insyde H2O UEFI Bios. Finally, the live USB also doesn't work. I'm feel so sad.

I see several brands use Insyde. One other: https://askubuntu.com/questions/150174/sony-vaio-with-insyde-h2o-efi-bios-will-not-boot-into-grub-efi Some have had to rename the Windows boot file name, but boot shim. Sony, HP & others workarounds:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win See IV.
